# typescript: array with properties / array as a class

Tags: arrays, class, typescript

I have this javascript code

```
class Customer{
    ...
}

let customers:Customer[]=[];
customers.lastDateRetrieved=new Date;
```

Somehow customers is both a class (it has properties) and an array.
How would you declare this construction in typescript? I can not find a way to derive from array (if that makes sense)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use an intersection type:

```
let customers:Customer[] & { lastDateRetrieved?: Date} =[];
customers.lastDateRetrieved=new Date ();
```

Or you can create a general type for this use case:

```
type ArrayWithProps<T> = T[] & { lastDateRetrieved?: Date}
let customers:ArrayWithProps<Customer> =[];
customers.lastDateRetrieved=new Date ();
```

You could also create a class derived from array, but then you would need to use the constructor of the class to initialize the array, and you can't use `[]`:

```
class ArrayWithProps<T> extends Array<T> {
    lastDateRetrieved: Date;
    constructor (... items : T[]){
        super(...items);
    }
}

var f = new ArrayWithProps();
f.push(new Customer());
f.lastDateRetrieved = new Date();
```

Comment: Great!. Could it be declared as a class inheriting from Array<T> (so it would have push/pop etc)  and having props/methods?

Comment: @Joan, added that option as well, you can create a derived class and do more, but you loose the ability to instantiate with a literal array `[]`

Answer (score -1):

You could try using the following syntax:

```
let customers: Array<Customer>=[]
```

It can be referred from their docs [for basic types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html)

Comment: That was not the question, he wants to be able to write `customers.lastDateRetrieved=new Date();` after. `Array<Customer>` will still not have the `lastDateRetrieved` property.